# F# deleting element from tree

Tags: f#, tree

I have a problem with function that should delete element from tree. It deletes whole node and not an single element.
Type tree code:

```
type tree =
    | Empty
    | Node of float * tree * tree
```

function code:

```
let deleteFromTree n = 
        let rec loop newTree = 
          function
            | Empty -> newTree
            | Node(a,b,c) -> 
                if a = n then loop newTree c
                elif a > n then Node(a,loop newTree b, c)
                else Node(a, b, loop newTree c)
        loop Empty
```

Comment: sadly i think is isnt quite as simple as your code makes it look, its not a simple error, but the lack of a whole lot of 'stuff', I'd google 'delete node ordered binary tree', I think there are some good pages that explain the 3 cases there are when you delete a node, 0 children (easy), 1 child (easy), 2 children ew...painful

Comment: there is even a previous question in the F# tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33325283/delete-an-element-from-a-binary-search-tree-in-f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code deletes a whole sub-tree because of how you handle the case when `a = n`. In that case, you return whatever you get by processing the right sub-tree `c` (using `loop newTree c`) but the variable `b` representing the left sub-tree is not used anywhere.

Given that you are comparing the values to search for `n`, I assume you have a binary search tree. In this case, the standard way for deleting an element is to find `Node(v, left, right)` where `v` is the value you are looking for and then replace `v` with the smallest value from `right` or greatest value from `left`. This way, you will get a binary search tree as the result, but you will be able to keep an inner node with both left and right sub-tree.

Let's say you want to replace `v` with the smallest value from the right. To do this, you will need a function `deleteMin` that takes a tree and returns a new tree, together with its smallest element. The smallest element is one where you have `Node(smallest, Empty, whatever)` - and when removing it, you can just return `smallest` alongside with the right sub-tree `whatever`.